# How to get a diagonal matrix of complex exponentials from a phase vector using linear algebra operations

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, diagonalization

I am given an amplitude vector $\mathbf{c} = [c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_N]^T$ and a phase vector $\boldsymbol{\theta} = [\theta_1, \theta_2, \cdots, \theta_N]^T$. From these two vectors, I want to get the following diagonal matrix:
$\mathbf{D} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1e^{j\theta_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & c_2e^{j\theta_2} & \cdots & \vdots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\0 & 0 & \cdots & c_Ne^{j\theta_N}\end{bmatrix}$.

Is there a way to write $\mathbf{D}$ in terms of the amplitude and phase vectors as a consequence of some linear algebra operations? I do not want to use $\textrm{diag}(c_1e^{j\theta_1}, c_2e^{j\theta_2}, \cdots, c_Ne^{j\theta_N})$.

-rd

Comment: There isn't a way to do this that I would consider "nicer" than using a diag operator. Maybe if you tell us what exactly you would do with such an expression for $D$, we could recommend an alternative approach

Comment: It's ok. I am not necessarily looking for a nicer expression. I only want to express $\mathbf{D}$ in terms of those two vectors. In my paper, I modify these vectors often and it will be nice to have a general expression for $\mathbf{D}$ to write in terms of these two vectors.

Comment: In terms of the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), you could write 
$$
D = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf c \odot \boldsymbol \theta),
$$
is that any better?

Comment: But $\theta$ should be in the exponent.

Comment: Maybe something like
$$
D = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf c \odot \exp[j\boldsymbol \theta])
$$
then

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is $\textrm{exp}[j\boldsymbol{\theta}]$ valid vector operation?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. That's a standard way to write entry-wise vector/matrix functions (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1235) for instance)